# in which currency does state trie's balance is stored?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, blocks, state-trie

My question is very simple and I couldn't find the answer for it.

There's a state trie in ethereum. Each state trie has address as key and value as an object which has `balance` as one of the keys.

I am curious what currency does ethereum store in balance ? is it wei, gwei, eth or even gas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in Wei. You can find the information in the Ethereum yellow paper, *Blocks, State and Transactions* section (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) :

> The world state (state), is a mapping between addresses (160-bit identifiers) and account
> states

The account object has 4 fields, including the `balance` which is formally defined as :

> A scalar value equal to the number of Wei
> owned by this address.

Note that Wei is the unit used by the EVM, all low level Ether operations  are done in Wei.